# Java Script Not Calling A function

Tags: javascript, web, resources, dynamics-crm-2013

I am creating a solution(web resource) for My CRM project. For that purpose i have written a map optimization code in java script using Bing API.

`retrieveAccountsCallBack` is retrieving addresses from the CRM. I am then using those address to find their Geo Codes.
Problem is when the code reaches to point `map.getCredentials(MakeGeocodeRequest)` it is then not going into the definition Of  `map.getCredentials(MakeGeocodeRequest)` function . It just passes this line  like its commented out .  But here is the twist some times it works but there is no definite pattern.

Here is the code:

```
function retrieveAccountsCallBack(retrievedAccounts) {

        totalAccountCount = totalAccountCount + retrievedAccounts.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < retrievedAccounts.length; i++) {

            var account = retrievedAccounts[i];
            //retLoc.push(account.new_address);
            waypoint = retrievedAccounts[i].new_address;
            map.getCredentials(MakeGeocodeRequest);
            ///////////////////////////////////////////

        }


    }
```

Code for MakeGeocodeRequest()

```
 function MakeGeocodeRequest(cred) {

        var geocodeRequest = "http://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=" + encodeURI(waypoint) + "&output=json&jsonp=GeocodeCallback&key=" + cred;
        CallRestService(geocodeRequest);
    }
```

Comment: You need to add a parameter to your `MakeGeocodeRequest` call, otherwise it's just passing the function itself to `map.getCredentials()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i figured it out!!!!
After thorough reading of Bing Maps API. i came to to know that there it was happening due to some anonymous functions in that API which i was not able to understand as it was written in compressed java script code.